# Problema para crear ficheros en java

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que introduces el nombre, la edad y la dirección de una persona y que luego te haga un fichero en el que se encuentren los datos que has introducido, pero no se como hacer para que se cree el fichero, alguien me puede ayudar?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int continuar;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{

    sitio[n_amigo] = new Amigo();
        
    System.out.println("Dame un nombre");
    sitio[n_amigo].nombre = entrada.next();
    System.out.println("Dame una edad");
    sitio[n_amigo].edad = entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Dame una direccion");
    sitio[n_amigo].nombre = entrada.next();
    n_amigo++;
    
do{
                System.out.println("Quieres introducir mas notas? 1 Si, 2 No");
                continuar = entrada.nextInt();
                if (continuar < 1 || continuar > 2){
                    System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
                }
            }while (continuar < 1 || continuar > 2);

}while(continuar!=2);
    
    for (int i=0; i<n_amigo; i++){
    System.out.println("El nombre del amigo "+i+" es: " +sitio[i].nombre);
    System.out.println("La direccion del amigo "+i+" es: " +sitio[i].direccion);        
    System.out.println("La edad del amigo "+i+" es: " +sitio[i].edad);
    
}
}
```

los arrays ya estan declarados, el codigo se ejecuta bien, lo unico que quiero es saber como meter todo eso dentro de un fichero

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un fichero en Java, puedes utilizar la clase **FileWriter**. La forma básica de utilizar esta clase es la siguiente:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("nombre_del_fichero.txt");
```

Esto creará un fichero con el nombre especificado y lo abrirá para escribir en él. Una vez que hayas terminado de escribir en el fichero, debes cerrarlo llamando al método close():

```
fw.close();
```

Para escribir en el fichero, puedes utilizar el método write() de la clase FileWriter. Este método recibe una cadena de texto como parámetro y escribe esa cadena en el fichero. Por ejemplo:

```
fw.write("Esta es una línea de texto");
```

En tu caso, podrías utilizar esta clase para escribir los datos de cada persona en el fichero. Por ejemplo:

```
// Creamos el fichero
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("amigos.txt");

// Escribimos los datos de cada amigo en el fichero
for (int i = 0; i < n_amigo; i++) {
  fw.write("Nombre: " + sitio[i].nombre + "\n");
  fw.write("Edad: " + sitio[i].edad + "\n");
  fw.write("Dirección: " + sitio[i].direccion + "\n");
}

// Cerramos el fichero
fw.close();
```

Comment: Relacionado [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes)

Comment: Algún aporte?? Tengo estudios y un Bootcamp full stack Java...

Comment: No olvides que también tienes una cuenta suspendida por *plagio* en el sitio en inglés... :/

Comment: Esto esta buenísimo!!! :'D